# Parse JSON object to DATA attr, with jQuery

Tags: json

I have DATA attribute with JSON string. I need to read this JSON, remove some information from this object, and write it back to DATA attr. Everything is fine, but write JSON object does not work. How to write JSON object to DATA attr ?

HTML

```
<div id="colors" data-colors='{"c1":"Red", "c2":"Yellow", "c3":"blue"}'></div>

<button data-color="c1">Red</button>
<button data-color="c2">Yellow</button>
<button data-color="c3">Blue</button>
```

jQuery

```
$("button").click( function(){

    var obj = JSON.parse($('#colors').attr('data-colors'));
    button_key = $(this).data('color');

    $.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
        if (key == button_key) {
                delete obj[button_key];
        }
    });

    $('#colors').attr('data-colors', obj ); // this is not working, HOW ?
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to jsonify the object when storing back.

```
$('#colors').attr('data-colors', JSON.stringify(obj));
```

**Tip:** use `.data('attribute-name')` to access data attribute. E.g.

```js
var color = $('#abc').data('color')

console.log(color)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="abc" data-color="red" >
```